# ASP.NET Core CSS not loading

Tags: asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core website works fine locally, but once published into internal server using 'FileSystem' publish option, site works but all CSS rules are broken, checked console, site.min.css did not getting loaded from wwwroot.

Code is very simple the one that getting generated by VS2017 when you select "Web Application", nothing fancy

Please advise

This is what i see when it loads by default
[seems like CSS is missing or emulation is not 11 IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyfxl.png)

This is what i see when i open F12 Developer tools
[F12 - Developer tools are ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CWxQ.png)

Answer:
I unchecked "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" and it works as expected in IE now too (Tools:Compatibility View Setting")
thank you ALL!

Comment: important thing,  Chrome works fine when site pulled from the server, the issue is only when used IE edge

Comment: Do you have the same problems when using a non-minified version?

Comment: yes, I tried both and also, tried removing "Development" and just go plain vanilla doesn't help, and changed project ENVIRONMENT = Production, no luck
Not sure how come Chrome works?

Comment: worth to mention, if i go F12 - Developer tools and make sure emulation set to 11 default all works fine, i set to persist and close Developer tools (x), it breaks the page again, please advise

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the console to show the url that it is trying to load the css from?